# Invalid keyword argument(s) in `compile` в keras

Tags: python, машинное-обучение, keras

Недавно воспроизводил код примеров из книги "Глубокое обучение на Python". Вот код:

```
from keras import models, layers, optimizers

model = models.Sequential()
model.add(layers.Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation='relu', input_shape=(150, 150, 3)))
model.add(layers.MaxPooling2D((2, 2)))
model.add(layers.Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu'))
model.add(layers.MaxPooling2D((2, 2)))
model.add(layers.Conv2D(128, (3, 3), activation='relu'))
model.add(layers.MaxPooling2D((2, 2)))
model.add(layers.Conv2D(128, (3, 3), activation='relu'))
model.add(layers.MaxPooling2D((2, 2)))
model.add(layers.Flatten())
model.add(layers.Dense(512, activation='relu'))
model.add(layers.Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))
model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy',
              oprimizer=optimizers.RMSprop(lr=1e-4),
              metrics=['acc'])
```

После попытки скомпилировать модель (последняя строчка) выдается следующее исключение:

```
TypeError: Invalid keyword argument(s) in `compile`: {'oprimizer'}
```

В чем дело?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

У вас просто описка. Правильное название параметра: `optimizer`